# struts 2 multipart maxSize action return

Tags: file-upload, struts2, limit, multipartform-data, actionresult

I have set in struts2 the property `"struts.multipart.maxSize=524288000"` so I can limit the overall upload size to that size. When I upload 2 files that exceed that limit, an exception occurs from the FileUpload interceptor

```
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (718551153) exceeds the configured maximum (524288000)
```

But the code does not reach the action with error so that I can return ERROR from the action and go to my custom error page and show the appropriate message. Instead it goes directly to application error and does not go to the action's method.

Any suggestions on how to return "ERROR" so I can get the proper redirection?

Comment: Did you configured your action to return ERROR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure `input` result for your action.

You could also configure `fileUpload` interceptor with `maximumSize` parameter for your action:

```
<action name="..." class="...">
  <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
    <param name="fileUpload.maximumSize">524288000</param>
  </interceptor-ref>

  <result name="input">error_page</result>
  <result>success_page</result>
</action>
```

Then you can override the text of error message by using this key:

```
struts.messages.error.file.too.large
```

Comment: I have configured an "input" result for my action, and an "error" result. But it does not use them for some reason. I don't want to set the interceptor in my action. I want it to work globally, not to have to set it every time.

Comment: @Panos: You can configure `fileUpload` interceptor globally in `<interceptors>` section of struts.xml. What do you mean by not using them?

Comment: By saying "not using them" I mean that I connected the debugger and put some breakpoints in the action's method. Started uploading the file, then got the max file size exception and the debugger never stopped in the the method, so it didn't execute the action's method. It bypassed it.

Comment: @Panos In which method? It's a validation error; IMO it shouldn't reach the action code.

Answer (score 0):

For the 'input' result to work correctly you have to have the Validation (org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor) and DefaultWorkflowInterceptors (com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor) as part of your interceptor stack.

Also you can define a custom result name to be used instead of 'input' like below

```
@InputConfig(resultName = "customInputResultNameWhenValidationFails")
public final String execute() throws Exception {
}
```